# Error on Laravel Mail configuration on new server

Tags: laravel, email

I got below error while working on server for Mail notification, were same configuration was working fine on localhost setup.

**Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 190sm4871925pgh.81 - gsmtp "**

Please help me on this if any one facing same issue earlier.

Comment: If not, please share more details - `Authentication Required` sounds like you've skipped it?

Comment: @NicoHaase same configuration working on local setup                                                                                MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=trupti.lad@******.co.in
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=trupti.lad@*****.co.in
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Fin_Service